# What is the use of ieee754 floating point exceptions?(NAN,OVERFLOW,INEXACT,UNDERFLOW,DIV0)

Tags: floating-point

I know the meaning of floatint point exceptions and I know how to get theses exceptions in C++ programming( function: fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT/FE_UNDERFLOW/...))

But can u tell me have u ever used theses exceptions in your project or during your programming?
What is the use of floating point exceptions?

Comment: Please clarify: I assume you are interested only in cases where IEEE-754 exceptions are unmasked, and therefore actually give rise to a system-level interrupt / signal such as `SIGFPE`.

Comment: Oh?ieee 754 exceptions can be used as system-level interrupt?yes ,div0 is a common one.But what about others?

Comment: `SIGFPE` is a catch-all signal for arithmetic errors with implementation dependent semantics. POSIX [specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) various subtypes, such as `FPE_FLTOVF`, `FPE_FLTUND`, and `FPE_FLTINV`. On 8088/8086 based PCs, floating-point exceptions from the 8087 math coprocessor were usually signaled via the NMI (non-maskable interrupt).

Comment: thank u,I get it......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating-point exceptions are generally used to improve the speed/accuracy of numerical computations. For instance, if you use a smaller size float by default (say single-precision) and the processor tells you the computation is inexact or an underflow or overflow occurred, you can re-evaluate using a larger size float (say double-precision), or even use software emulation to compute an answer with much-larger precision as needed. Assuming the computations mostly fit into the smaller format, it'll run faster, or you'll have more opportunities to vectorize. (Imagine SSE2/AVX/AVX512 line of instructions.) You can then trap and "repeat" the problematic ones using a bigger size.

But you're right that for most programs these exceptions go un-trapped, and people usually ignore them. And arguably that's a reasonable thing to do, as most programs don't do intensive numerical analysis. Here's a paper from 1996 that you should read for details on how these exceptions can be put to good use: [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/264/papers/hauser.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Efateman/264/papers/hauser.pdf)